# shared library : global text symbol being converted to local text type

Tags: shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I have a static library, let's call this as static_lib_1.a. I have a function let's say "func_1" within this static library.
When i run 'nm' command over this static library it show :

```
0x000000 T xxxfunc_1xxx
```

Which is perfectly fine. func_1 is reported is a global text symbol.

I use this library to link into a shared library, let say "shared_lib_2.so". Now when is do nm on this shared library i get is :

```
0x000000 t xxxfunc_1xxx
```

Now any other shared object linking to this "shared_lib_2.so" reports this symbol as undefined reference.
What made this symbol type changed from global to local text ?

I am using gcc to compile the same.